# Разработка виджета. Прогресс анимации

Tags: android, android-customview

Добрый вечер. Пишу свой кастомный виджет, в котором присутствует анимация. Нужно поставить на прогресс анимации слушатель и реализовать кэлбэк, чтобы можно было использовать процент прогресса для действий разработчика.

То, что я хочу, присутствует в `BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback`, пытался раздобыть код этого класса (или интерфейса, я даже не знаю что для этого используется) - безрезультатно. Помогите любыми идеями. Спасибо

Comment: Обычно все-таки наоборот, есть источник прогресса, а виджет их только показывает. Либо я не понял вопрос.

Comment: Я просто не знаю как объяснить. Нужно как-то написать в виджете слушатель на прогресс анимации и добавить возможность в активности его использовать. Вроде верно вы поняли

Comment: Тогда рассказывайте, почему не наоборот?

Comment: Не пойму никак :D

Comment: Ну, думай. :) Андроид - достаточно гибкая система. Тупик в решении обычно означает ошибку в архитектуре. Вряд ли у тебя задача, которая противоречит концепции UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в чём проблема с исходным кодом? Кажется, [здесь](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.java) как раз те самые исходники.

Но вообще, насколько я знаю, не существует способа получить именно событие прогресса анимации, хотя можно дождаться окончания одной анимации с помощью [`Animation.AnimationListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html).

Как вариант можно объединить несколько анимаций в цепочку с помощью [`AnimatorSet.playSequentially`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html#playSequentially(android.animation.Animator...)), где так же можно отслеживать окончание анимаций с помощью [`Animator.AnimatorListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html). Увы, не уверен в производительности последнего решения.

Comment: Видимо решений нет вообще.

Comment: А может юзать `CountDownTimer`? Чето доперло вроде. Вместе с анимацией его запускать в качестве шага брать миллисекунду. `duration` анимации ставить как финиш. В методе `onTick` менять переменную изначально равную нулю на миллисекунду больше. Но вот как все прописать не пойму.

Comment: Не пойму как прописать саму логику использования этой переменной в активности. Я додумал. Можно делить переменную на `duration` анимации и получить значение типа `float`

Comment: @СергейГрушин А зачем какие-то дополнительные переменные? Ваш `onTick` -- это и есть место вызова колбэка. Вы знаете сколько времени всего требуется на операцию и сколько времени уже прошло, исходя из этого имеет процент выполнения. Вот и вызывайте необходимый Вам код прямо из `onTick`. Только тогда стоит частоту тиков поставить поменьше, чтобы колбэк не вызывался слишком часто. А расскажите подробнее, что вообще за задача? Может можно как-то сделать иначе.

Comment: Я пишу `FlipView`. Есть две либы на гитхабе но я хочу сделать ещё лучше. Да и вообще.. Не понял )) У меня нет задачи я пишу кастомный вью и хочу напичкать его всем что можно чтобы было хорошее юзабилити и пользователь-разработчик без проблем адаптировался в нем. А нужды то у всех разные.